# How to find a string at a specific location mixed not english in java?

Tags: regex

How to find a string at a specific location with regex?

choryangStn_110_220114_일_0.sbm

choryangStn_110_220114_이_0.sbm

choryangStn_110_220114_삼_0.sbm

At work, I would like to bring `일`, `이`, `삼`

I tried

```
String filename = "choryangStn_110_220114_일_0.sbm";
filename.replaceAll(".*_(\\w+)_\\d+\\.\\w+", "$1");
```

If do like this, it will not work properly.

I wonder how can I satisfy `\\w or [가-힣]` .

`filename.replaceAll(".*_(\\w+)||[가-힣]_\\d+\\.\\w+", "$1");`

`filename.replaceAll(".*_(\\w+||[가-힣])_\\d+\\.\\w+", "$1");`

Both of the above sentences don't work properly.

I wonder how this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `replaceFirst()`:

```
(?U)^.*_(\\w+)_\\d+\\.\\w+$
```

The `(?U)` is an embedded flag option that is equivalent of [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) option that makes all shorthand character classes Unicode-aware.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oDUwz/2) and the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/CLbupU):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String strings[]  = {"choryangStn_110_220114_일_0.sbm",
            "choryangStn_110_220114_이_0.sbm",
            "choryangStn_110_220114_삼_0.sbm"
        };
        String regex = "(?U)^.*_(\\w+)_\\d+\\.\\w+$";
        for(String text : strings)
        {
            System.out.println("'" + text + "' => '" + text.replaceFirst(regex, "$1") + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'choryangStn_110_220114_일_0.sbm' => '일'
'choryangStn_110_220114_이_0.sbm' => '이'
'choryangStn_110_220114_삼_0.sbm' => '삼'
```